# Number of dependent variables

Tags: anova, repeated-measures, manova

I have data from raters who each provided two ratings for a large set of categories. They were asked to rate how coherent each category was on a scale of 0 (members totally dissimilar) to 9 (members highly similar) and they did this twice: first, deciding if the category members had similar sizes, and, second, whether the category members has similar shapes (or something quite like this anyway - the two rating questions assessed different but related things).

I averaged across the raters so now I have two ratings for each of my categories (size and shape) and there are various factors for the categories.

I want to know whether category membership is best defined in terms of size, shape or a combination of both ... so I want to directly compare the size and shape ratings.

This seems like a daft question but it's not clear to me how many dependent measures I have. I want to use the means of the raters in a repeated-measures ANOVA with rating as the dependent and instructions for rating instructions (size vs shape) as a repeated-measure factor. This allows me to directly compare the ratings.

However, it could well be argued I have two dependent variables so I should be doing two separate ANOVAs (or a MANOVA).

It seems like there could be a continuum from a situation which is definitely repeated measures using the same dependent variable (if I'd asked the raters to answer exactly the same question about shape similarity using exactly the same scale twice, 24 hours apart) to it definitely being two dependent variables (if I'd asked raters about the shape of the members and then about how expensive they were). My case seems to fall somewhere between.

Correlation between the two types of ratings was low (-.16).